# Freetype2 returns bigger size value than expected

Tags: c++, fonts, freetype, freetype2

I want to get specific size of char bitmap, so use FT_Set_Pixel_Sizes() like below.

```
 error = FT_Set_Pixel_Sizes( ftFace, 0, 28 ); // want to get 28px size
```

But when get Metrics from freetype2, the sum of ascender and descender is 29.(24-(-5)).

```
float FROM_266 = 1.0f/64.0f;
FT_Size_Metrics& ftMetrics = ftFace->size->metrics;
printf("%f %f\n",  static_cast< float >( ftMetrics.ascender  ) * FROM_266, static_cast< float >( ftMetrics.descender ) * FROM_266);
// result : 24 -5
```

I think it should be 28 because I set the desired size as 28px.

Can sum of ascender and descender bigger than desired size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can sum of ascender and descender bigger than desired size?

[Yes](https://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/glyphs/index.html).